# Doctrine Single Table Inheritance Custom Discriminator Map

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create an Entity which uses two columns for the `DiscriminatorColumn`?

A table exists with 3 columns:

- id (primary key)
- main_type (varchar 5)
- sub_type (int 4)

I have setup Inheritance for main_type:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="main_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "news" = "News", 
 *  "blog" = "Blog", 
 *  "event" = "AbstractEvent", 
 * })  
 */
 abstract class AbstractArtcile
```

This works so far, however Event can have many sub_types. Within event the following is required:

```
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="sub_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  1 = "Event\Sport", 
 *  2 = "Event\Night", 
 *  3 = "Event\Epic", 
 * })  
 abstract class AbstractEvent
```

However this does not work because it doesn't know to run the discriminator map on AbsractEvent as well.

I am aware the mapping must be set at the top most level and this is why the above doesn't work.

> The @InheritanceType and @DiscriminatorColumn must be specified on the topmost class that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy.
>   http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Can a custom discriminator be used? If so how?

Or is the better solution to create a new column which combines the values in main_type and sub_type and use these for the map i.e. news-0, blog-0, event-1, event-2, event-3?

The table structure is from a legacy system and can not be modified but additional columns can be added.

Comment: Not sure if it would help you further with your problem. However, have you tried using a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for your `AbstractEvent`. If you'd have just `Event`, using a trait for categories you might be able to work around the problem. Events could hold the types of events (Sport/Night/Epic/Whatever).